# Tracked video not showing in the 3D viewport in rendered mode

Tags: tracking, compositing-nodes

When I try to composite this with my cg object it doesn't work. After completing the tracking I have set the tracking scene, but the video behind doesn't works or shows while in render mode(cycles).
[image]

but as you can see it does shows the tracker point but both things doesn't composite.

This is my node setup in the compositor.
[image]

Comment: To composite it has to be setup in the compositor. Can you please show your compositor setup?

Comment: plz check below

Comment: still can't see my video in the view port even after setting up the background.

Comment: Is your monkey rendered with transparent film enabled?

Comment: yes it is and also rendering perfectly but can't see the video in viewport even after setting up the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have a transparent background in the render layer, enable *Film*  *Transparent*.

I checked into the compositor and transparent render would have the checker background as shown here:

[image]

[image]

(For 2.7x)
[image]